# how to make a tag change properties after a specific input is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a quiz website for a school project. Whenever a correct answer is selected `(input type=radio)` then I want the line adjacent to it to become `green` and when an incorrect answer is selected I want the line to become `red`.

Is there any way to do this using `css` only and not `JavaScript`.

Comment: add your code here

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In this case, at the very least, your HTML. Ideally we would also like to see the JavaScript you've managed to come up with so far (and a specific explanation of where exactly you are stuck / what does not work).

Comment: sorry i haven't written any code till now, I was planning my website and thought of incorporating this idea into my project but I had no idea how to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have some attribute in your input indicating that it's the right option and then listen for it in CSS using the `[attribute="value"]` then select the next tag (p etc.) with some kind of operator (like `+`)

[JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7e69pkko/)

Comment: Thank You a lot! When you add +p to :checked, then does it mean that if this option is checked then p tag should turn red. I didn't understand the use of that +p, it would be great if someone explained it to me

Comment: @AakarshSingh You can read up on them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). The `+` operator selects the only `p` tag immediately after the specified selector (in our case the checked radio button).

Answer (score 0):

You can see this tutorial:
https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-ux-html-css/

The beginning is in css without js.

See also all css selectors, you can find your happiness:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Good work !

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done without involving javascript or jquery. You must have to trigger your code when checkbox is selected. Here is an example:

```js
function myFunction() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName('rd1');
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        // use if condition to check if selected answer is correct or not 
        // and then simply change text color OR add a css class, which have predefined text colors for success and error
       
        alert(radios[i].value);

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="rd1" id="red" value="Option 1" onchange="myFunction()"><label>Option 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="rd1" id="red" value="Option 2" onchange="myFunction()"><label>Option 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="rd1" id="red" value="Option 3" onchange="myFunction()"><label>Option 3</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="rd1" id="red" value="Option 4" onchange="myFunction()"><label>Option 4</label><br>
```